# ExtJS4 to ExtJs5 Migation - ext-all-debug.js - cacheRefEls-function

Tags: extjs4, migration, extjs5

I am migrating a project **from ExtJs4 to ExtJs5**.
In my **Firefox (Version 33.0.2)**-Debug-View **(Firebug Version 2.0.4)** i can see the following **Console-output**, after refreshing my browser window:

```
TypeError: dom.querySelectorAll is not a function
http://localhost:8080/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js
Line 34531
```

*How to fix that error* **OR** *how to find out which part of my own code does cause **ext-all-debug.js** to nag?*

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: @Lolo: Please read the second sentence out loud for yourself.

Comment: Firefox has 33 major releases, and trust me, version may make difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the native ExtJs5 **cacheRefEls**-function defined inside **ext-all-debug.js** into the following, after putting multiple **console.log()** into it, which indicated that the dom is not returning a tree:

```
cacheRefEls: function(el) {
    el = el || this.el;

    var cache = null;
        try{
            cache = Ext.cache,
            El = Ext.dom.Element,
            dom = el.isElement ? el.dom : el,
            refs = dom.querySelectorAll('[data-ref]'),
            len = refs.length,
            ref, i;
            //console.log("Success: 'Nodelist' returned by 'el.dom.querySelectorAll('[data-ref]')' for el--->"+el + " 'cache-variable is set!'");
         }catch(err){
             //console.log("Error: No 'Nodelist' returned by 'el.dom.querySelectorAll('[data-ref]')' for el--->"+el + " 'Couldn't set cache-variable!'");
         }

         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             ref = refs[i];
             if (!cache[ref.id]) {
                  new El(ref);
             }
         }
}
```

This avoids that the **dom**-tree is accessed for **el**'s that do not have such a tree, like for example **Text**-objects.

*P.S.: Use this fix with care, because it fiddles around with the native code provided by Sencha.*